# How to convert microsoft graph 365 Users Profile Photos from binary data to a readable image format

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have successfully displayed informations about admin users profiles Photos using Microsoft Graph API in PHP, below is the code that I used

```php
<?php
session_start();
echo $acc = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer $acc",
        "accept: application/json",
        "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ) ,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$res = json_decode($response);
$res1 = json_decode($response, true);
$res1['@odata.context'];
echo 'photo <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($res1['@odata.context']) . '"/>';
echo '<p>photo Name : ' . $res1['@odata.context'] . '</p> 
      <img src="' . $res1['@odata.context'] . '"><br />';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($response, true) . '</pre>';

if ($err)
{
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else
{
}
?>
```

Header returned with a successful call:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
request-id: dc3a8a0c-0ff1-455f-afe8-5cdeb6b70a1b
client-request-id: dc3a8a0c-0ff1-455f-afe8-5cdeb6b70a1b
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_14","ADSiteName":"CHI"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Duration: 121.1991
Date: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 10:21:55 GMT
```

JSON returned:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('2b7f8bf2-3d23-43e6-b068-39aa5009fed7')/photo/$entity",
    "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"10F9EA34\"",
    "id": "504X504",
    "height": 504,
    "width": 504
}
```

MY problem is that when I tried to display the image in an image link in php
 as per the json Curl result in php, it does show the image.

How do I convert the binary returned Image data to browser image readable format

```
Below is the new error message after implementing Marc Solutions

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer $acc",
    "accept: image/jpeg",
    "content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

)



HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 93186bcd-05ad-41b5-bafe-8f5c4d7a3952
client-request-id: 93186bcd-05ad-41b5-bafe-8f5c4d7a3952
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_14","ADSiteName":"CHI"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Duration: 104.1582
Date: Sun, 03 Dec 2017 16:09:14 GMT

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the acceptable MIME types for the request. The supported type(s) 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...' do not match any of the acceptable MIME types 'image/jpeg'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "93186bcd-05ad-41b5-bafe-8f5c4d7a3952",
      "date": "2017-12-03T16:09:14"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$value` parameter is used to request the actual image. Your call however is requesting isn't URL Encoding the `$` and an it looks like PHP/Curl is just ignoring the result.

Try using the URL Encoded version of `%24value` instead.

```php
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/%24value",
```

Comment: At Marc Lafleur, I have updated my code with your solution but shows error below

Comment: At Marc, I have added your solution, it displays error below  

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the acceptable MIME types for the request. The supported type(s) 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false,  etc

Comment: I have also updated my question/post to reflect the full details of the error that it showed. Please me. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `accept` header entirely. Also be sure that you're requesting `/$value`.

Comment: I have removed the accepted header  but the result does not contain the actual image hence below is the result. 
`{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('2b7f8bf2-3d23-43e6-b068-39aa5009fed7')/photo/$entity","@odata.mediaContentType":"image/jpeg","@odata.mediaEtag":"\"10F9EA34\"","id":"504X504","height":504,"width":504}`

Comment: If you look at `@odata.context`, you're not  requesting `/$value`. I suspect the library you're using isn't URL encoding. Try replacing `$value` with it's url encoded equivalent of `%24value`.

Comment: at Marc, %24value works, however it seems to displays image in a binary format. How do I get the image runs in a browser by calling the json results in an image format.  I have tried  
 `echo "<img src='$res'><br>";
echo "<img src='$res1'>";`

Comment: JSON is a serialized representation of a object, not an encoding. In order to display the image in an `img` tag, you'll need to provide a data url (`data:image/gif;base64,{base64-image}`). See http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/ for an overview of how this works.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I'd like to clarify something. Curl isn't really ignoring the result in this case. `$value` is being used while encapsulated between double quotes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing meaning PHP will try to replace `$value` with its value within PHP. Which I assume is empty, so the request url ends with 'photo/'. I think single quotes would suffice as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the image, you need to use $value like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

Comment: that is exactly what I used.I think there is a need to convert the image to browser readable format

Comment: At Jason Rivera,I have edited my post with full details of my work so far and where am currently having issues