# Get Profile image from Microsoft Graph

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

I am trying to get the profile image of the current user with Microsoft Graph. I am using the [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

The code below gets the the photo, but returns the binary data of the jpeg file.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        session_start();

    $graph = new Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $photo = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/me/photo/\$value")
                           ->execute();

    return $photo->getRawBody();
```

[It seems](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/office-365-groups-api/) that I need to set the response type to blob before I can use the image in a more normal way, but how do I do that with Guzzle?

I also tried it with cUrl, but the same issue, all I get is binary data:

```
$curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/\$value",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer $at",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "Content-type: image/jpeg",
            "Accept: blob",
            "postman-token: caccedb3-8253-e6aa-7e30-25052bc28f2f"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614068/how-to-convert-microsoft-graph-365-users-profile-photos-from-binary-data-to-a-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found it finally:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/48x48/\$value",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer $at",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "postman-token: 2d4b85a3-5490-3f58-ff74-52e0a98286ec"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return base64_encode($response);
    }
```

And in the template:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{\O365\Profile::photo()}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you're using Laravel (which you tagged)*

Add the `Content-Type` header to your response, so the browser understands what type of data it is:

```
return response($response)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
```

Comment: But then I still have a 'binary' image, how can I use that in the laravel blade template? 
Because simply this is not working:
    <img width="25" height="25" src="{{$photo}}"

Comment: @LazyAdmin Of course that won't work. You should provide the `<img>` tag with a URL, not raw data (although it's possible, I wouldn't recommend it in this case). So point the `src=` attribute to your controller that fetches the profile image.

Comment: Given that this is pretty small (48x48), you could use a `data` tag with the base64 encoded image directly in the `src` attribute like this:
(data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64-image})`.

Comment: The problem is that I get the data returned like below

`�����JFIF��`�`�����C�  

 $.' " ,#(7),01444'9="82<.342���C" ="" ="" 2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����0�0"��������������="" �������}�!1aqa"q2���#b��`